# Mongodb query where hour in datetime gte

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have to group and count a collection within a given period where the hour is after 4pm. I have a query which creates the count within the given period but I don't know how to query for a given hour.

Here are my queries so far, which both work fine:

```
db.appointment.group({
    key: { operator: 1 },
    cond: {
        department: "Residential",
        action: "MOVE",
        created: {
            $gte: ISODate("2016-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            $lt:ISODate("2016-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        },
    },
    reduce: function(curr, result){ result.count++; },
    initial: { count: 1 }
})
```

and

```
db.appointment.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            department: "Residential",
            action: "MOVE",
            created:{
                $gte: ISODate("2016-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
                $lt:ISODate("2016-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$operator",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

What is missing now is: where hour from created is `$gte: 16`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** as follows:

```
db.appointment.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": { 
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$and": [  
                        { "$eq": [ "$department", "Residential" ] },
                        { "$eq": [ "$action", "MOVE" ] },
                        { "$gte": [ "$created", ISODate("2016-09-01") ] },
                        { "$lt": [ "$created", ISODate("2016-10-01") ] },
                        { "$gte": [ { "$hour": "$created" }, 16 ] }
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$operator",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Where does `$hour` come from to be comparable in this?

Comment: From the [Aggregation Date Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators). The [**`$hour`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/#exp._S_hour) operator returns the hour for a date as a number between 0 and 23.